# How does a microservices is essential in application development

Tags: microservices

referred to some posts and videos for Microservices that how it works and what is the benefit of it but none of the examples or videos satisfy my confusion. can anyone help and can share some live examples which can be related to the App development methodology.

Comment: Hi Praveen and welcome. The question you have asked is not a good fit for Stackoverflow, which is designed for specific programming problems only. You question in it's current form will be closed. If you have a programming related problem, please feel free to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn´t essential but it is necessary according to the [problem you are trying to solve](https://educosta.dev/blog/what-is-microservice/). The fact that microservices becomes a popular way to build application does not mean it solve all the problems.

There are cases [where you should rethink the use of microservice](https://educosta.dev/blog/5-facts-that-will-make-you-rethink-the-use-of-microservice/) and to build a monolith application can be good enough for your scenarios or you will end with a [distrbuted big ball of mud](http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/2014/07/06/distributed_big_balls_of_mud.html).

The [Law of the instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) says something like:

```
If the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.
```

So, we can not make the assumption that microservice is essential for all scenarios in application development.